# How can I capture maya 3d view with QPixmap?

Tags: pyqt4, screen-capture, maya, qpixmap

I make a screen capture script for maya.
So, I deal the job with QPixmap class.

I write the script like that.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sip
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui

def getMayaWindow():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

pm = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(getMayaWindow().winId())
pm.save('c:/test.png')
```

but, it can't grab the 3Dview, so it can't work.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. When I ran this snippet I got this: http://tinypic.com/r/23t1ugp/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue.
There is the solution by [Nathan Horne](http://nathanhorne.com/?p=261) which works fine.
However, if you want to get the QWidget object that a certain M3dView uses, follow these steps:

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sip

view = apiUI.M3dView.active3dView()
widget_ptr = view.widget()
widget = sip.wrapinstance(long(widget_ptr), QtCore.QObject)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(widget)
```

As you know, you can then save the pixmap to a file or use it directly for another QWidget.
Strangely enough, the result seems a mess (or at least less predictable) and I recommend using Nathan Horne's solution.

Comment: Does it work properly? It found modelPanel and "widget" is the right panel. But, QPixmap.grabWidget create a just "black" pixmap. It has a right size, but I can't get wished image.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine for me, running on OSX, Maya 2012 x64

[image: Output from your script]

Alternatively, if your goal is to screencap JUST the 3d viewport, you could try using a playblast:

```
cmds.playblast( frame=cmds.currentTime(q=True),
                f="/tmp/test.png", 
                fo=True, fmt="image", viewer=False,
                c="PNG", quality=70 )
```